# How to insert data into multiple tables in one request using sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, orm

I have three tables, and the relationship is as below.
[image]

The object that I generate in the frontend and that I pass to the backend:

```
{
  name: "Model1",
  model_2: [
    {
      name: "Model2",
      model_3: [
        {
          name: "Model3"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I need to know how to make the relationships and how to pass the object to `create` in the `module_1` controller so that it inserts the values.

How can I do it?